# HeadFirst Java MixFor5 excercise - break clause

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have been struggling with the break clause aspect of an exercise in the Java Headfirst book( CH5: p121 for reference). I understand how the below code works when the break clause isn't initiated but when it is, I don't get the results I expected.
Can someone please walk me through this?

I understand that the break clause should be activated when the input value is either `x = x + 0` or `x = x + 6`

Below is the exercise code

```
class MixFor5 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 30;
        for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {
            for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
                x = x + 0; //input value
                y = y - 2;
                if (x == 6) {
                    break;
                }
                x = x + 3;
            }
            y = y - 2;
        }
        System.out.println((x + " " + y));
    }
}
```

My understanding would be that the inner loop would break if x == 6 and thus everything within the inner loop will discontinue including the additional `x = x + 3`

For x = x + 0. My expected result was x = 6 | y = 18 (actual result x = 6 | y = 14)

For x = x + 6. My expected result was x = 6 | y = 22 (actual result x = 60 | y = 10)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For x = x + 0

```
outer = 0;
 inner = 4;
   x=x+0, x!=6;
   x=x+3=3;
   y=30-2=28;
 inner = 3;
  x=3;
  y=28-2=26;
  3 != 6;
  x=3+3;
 inner = 2;
  x==6;
  y=24;
  break;
  y=22;
outer=1;
 inner=4;
  x==6;
  y=20;
  break;
  y=18;
outer=2;
 inner=4;
  x==6;
  y=16;
  break;
  y=14;
```

for x=x+6

```
outer=0; 
 inner=4;
  x=6;
  y=28;
  break;
  y=26;
outer=1;
 inner=4;
  x=6+6+3;
  y=24;
 inner=3;
  x=15+6+3;
  y=22;
 inner=2;
  x=33;
  y=20;
  y=18;
outer=2;
 inner=4;
  x=42;
  y=16;
 inner=3;
  x=51;
  y=14;
 inner=2;
  x=60;
  y=12;
  y=10;
```

hope this would help.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question "understand how the below code works". You may want to read [answer].